# display complex object properties in view asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc

If I have two models

```
class Person {
 public string Name {get;set;}
 public DateOfBirth DOB {get;set;}
}

class DateOfBirth {
 public int Year {get;set;}
 public int Month {get;set;}
 public int Day {get;set;}
}
```

and a view that tries to display this information

```
@model Person
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
 <td>
  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
 </td>
 <td>
  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DOB.Year)
 </td>
</tr>
```

What is the correct way of getting the values/information from the complex object "DateOfBirth"?
I'm currently trying this and the Year value is not being displayed, but the Name is being displayed because its just a string.

Thanks guys!

Comment: The Year is just an `int`...

Comment: @StriplingWarrior but its inside the DateOfBirth object

Comment: What are you trying to get out of DisplayFor in this case? Why not just say `@item.DOB.Year`?

Comment: Because I didn't know @item exists.. Im new to asp.net

Comment: `@` just switches you into C# mode. `Html` is just a property on your view that has some helper methods on it, but if there's a C# variable named `item` then you can access it via `@item`. The view code you posted doesn't really work, though: your model is supposed to be a `Person`, but then you're iterating over it with a `for` loop.

Comment: Because I seeded the database with a list of Person objects.. I just tried @item.DOB.Year, got an exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. The view was a scaffolded view, generated by visual studio

Comment: If you're getting a null reference exception from @item.DOB.Year, then either `item` is null or `item.DOB` is null. Probably the latter. Did you forget to populate the DOB property on the Person objects?

Comment: I think I populated it, will double check

Comment: Why would you create a custom class for this? Just use a `DateTime`. You'll still be able to access `Year`, `Month`, and `Day` individually, as `DateTime` exposes those properties.

Comment: @ChrisPratt it was for context, I'm not doing this exact thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're letting things get overly complicated with DisplayFor. You probably mean to do something like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<Person>
@foreach (var person in Model) {
<tr>
 <td>
  @person.Name
 </td>
 <td>
  @person.DOB.Year
 </td>
</tr>
```

When you start building a larger product, editor and display templates will allow you to get a lot of code reuse when you need to display basic information from your view models. But for now, that may be just a little more advanced than you need.